# What kinds of graphs are known to exhibit sharp threshold for bernoulli percolation?

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, reference-request, random-graphs, percolation

What kinds of graphs are known to exhibit *sharp threshold* for independent bernoulli percolation? Here, sharp threshold stands for exponential decay of the probability of the cluster range below the critical point $p_c$ and superlinear growth of $\theta$ above $p_c$ (the mean field lower bound) .

More precisely, i would like to know for what classes of graphs $G$ the following two properties (which are well known for $\mathbb{Z}^d$) hold. If $B_n$ is a ball of radius $n$ centered at the origin (denoted by $0$),
$$
\mathbb{P}_p(0 \text{ is connected to }\partial B_n)\leq e^{-cn}, \text{   for }p<p_c.
$$
and
$$
\theta(p):=\mathbb{P}_p(0\leftrightarrow \infty)\geq c(p-p_c),  \text{   for }p>p_c.
$$

sharp thresholds for percolation in a more general meaning are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting proof of the statement you make is with Hugo Duminil-Copin and Vincent Tassion, in this article:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03050.pdf